# How to operate the elements of an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have to operate a 4 elements array, calculating the difference between the adjacent elements and creating a new array with the resulting differnece. The last element should be colindant with the first one.

example:

```
firstArray=[0,1,2,3];
secondArray = newArray();
```

The second array will be:

```
secondArray[0]: 1-0 = 1
secondArray[1]: 2-1 = 1
secondArray[2]: 3-2 = 1
secondArray[3]: 3-0 = 3
```

So the new Array should be `secondArray=[1,1,1,3]`

I tried to do it with a for loop but when the third array is going to be operate it always operate the firstArray[3] - secondArray[0]... when it should be fistArray[3] - firstArray[0]

How can operate the firstArray to differentiate it from the new created secondArray?

Thank you!

Comment: Shouldn’t the last be `0-3 = -3`?

Comment: What does `[1, 4, 19, -55, 20]` give?

Comment: @red: Could you please give a description of each result, using the notation I've used in my answer? I'm a bit confused by the way you wrote it. It looks to me like you want the n-1th element to substract the 0th element, which seems to break your pattern.

Comment: @KennyTM using your array, the resulting array should be:

[3, 15, 74, 75, 19]

between two adjacent numbers the difference should always be the result of subtract the higher number minus the smaller.

Comment: @FrustratedWithFormsDesigner:
Using the example given by KennyTM, with that array I shoul generate a serie like this one:

[1, 4, 19, -55, 20]

[3,15,74,75,19]  
[12,59,1,56,16]  
[47,58,55,40,4]  
[11,3,15,36,43]  
  
sorry if my question is not clear
thx a lot

Comment: @red: what would it look like with the indices? I'm confused about which element should subtracted from which (or even why). It is not at all clear to me (and I don't have the time to do all the calculations by hand). I thought your initial question was for an output that consisted of a single array, but your comment here implies your output consists of a *series* of arrays. Huh?

Comment: @FrustratedWithFormsDesigner:

first Array generated:

[4-1=3, 19-4=15, 19-(-55)=74, 20-1=19]
  
second:

[3-15=12, 74-15=59, 75-74=1, 75-19=56, 19-3=16]

third:

[59-12=47, 59-1=58, 56-1=55, 56-16=40, 16-12=4]

and so on...

always the new array is the result of calculate the difference between the higher number minus the smaller of the previous array..

sorry for the confusion generated (i'm new in this..)

and thank you for yopur support!

Comment: @FrustratedWithFormsDesigne: you're correct!..the output is a series of arrays...

Comment: @red: So how do you know which value to subtract from which? And how many output arrays should there be? I am still very fuzzy on this.

Comment: the point is to iterate over the first array and build a series of new arrays where...

the first element is the result of the difference between the first and the second (always the higher minus the smaller)... the second is the differnce between the sencond and the third (the higher minus the smaller)... and so on

after the last element it has to wrap round to the start again. In an array of 4 elements it should be:

a) if the third element is the higher:
secondArray[3] = firstArray[3] - firstArray[0]

b) if the first element is the higher:
secondArray[3] = firstArray[0] - firstArray[3]

Comment: @FrustratedWithFormsDesigne:
the point is to iterate over the first array and build a series of new arrays where the first element is the result of the difference between the first and the second (always the higher minus the smaller)... the second is the differnce between the sencond and the third..and so on. After the last element it has to wrap round to the start again. In an array of 4 elements it should be:
a) if the third element is the higher:
secondArray[3] = firstArray[3] - firstArray[0]
b) if the first element is the higher:
secondArray[3] = firstArray[0] - firstArray[3]

Comment: @red: AHA! "first element [in the output] is the result of the difference between the first [in the input] and second [in the input]" ... is the description I was missing to understand the pattern.

Comment: @red: See update to my post below.

Answer (score 1):

You never said anythign about a 3rd array in your example.

Is this what you're trying to do?

```
secondArray[0] = firstArray[1]-firstArray[0];
secondArray[1] = firstArray[2]-firstArray[1];
secondArray[2] = firstArray[3]-firstArray[2];
secondArray[3] = firstArray[0]-firstArray[3];
```

If you are in a loop, the expression could be

```
secondArray[i] = firstArray[(i+1)%arrayLength]-firstArray[i];
```

**UPDATE:**

```
secondArray[i] = Max(firstArray[(i+1)%arrayLength],firstArray[i]) - Min(firstArray[(i+1)%arrayLength],firstArray[i]);
```

Using Max and Min will get the larger and smaller of the two elements in question. Does that help?

Comment: Question states `fistArray[3] - firstArray[0]`, you have it the other way round...

Answer (score 0):

in your loop:

```
if (i == 3)
firstArray[i] - firstArray[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var firstArray = [0,1,2,3],
    secondArray = [];
firstArray.forEach(function(val, i, arr) {
    secondArray[i] = arr[(i+1)%arr.length] - val;
});
```

---

**Edit**    A solution without `forEach`:

```
for (var i=0; i<firstArray.length; ++i) {
    secondArray[i] = firstArray[(i+1)%firstArray.length] - firstArray[i];
}
```

Comment: forEach only works in some browsers, your solution should probably support IE as well.

Comment: +1 for that reason. Lowest common denominator thinking would have you only reading the Sun and eating McDonalds. Get out of the gutter.

Answer (score 0):

```
input = [1, 4, 19, -55, 20];

function f(a) {
   function next(a) {
     var t = [], l = a.length;
     for (var i = 1; i < l; ++ i)
       t.push(Math.abs(a[i] - a[i-1]));
     t.push(Math.abs(a[l-1] - a[0]));
     return t;
   }

   var l = a.length;
   var result = [a];
   for (var i = 0; i < l-1; ++ i)
     result.push(next(result[i]));
   return result;
}

f(input);
// [[1, 4, 19, -55, 20], [3, 15, 74, 75, 19], [12, 59, 1, 56, 16], [47, 58, 55, 40, 4], [11, 3, 15, 36, 43]]
```